# Add item to form data vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I need to add a value (position) to my vuejs form data on submit.

```
 data() {
   return {
     position: "Assistant",
      form: {
       firstname: null,
       lastname: null,
     },
   };
 }
```

I tried the following on submit but it doesn't work:

**Method**

```
  onSubmit() {    
    this.form.push({
            position: this.position,
        })
  }
```

How do I append this value to data object?

Comment: form is an object. you can not use push.  The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push works with an array, not with an object.

form is an object. So, you can add a property in these ways:

```
this.form.position = this.position;

this.form['position'] = this.position;
```